# LinkedIn API, Reading groups posts issue

Tags: php, api, zend-framework, linkedin-api

I am using Zend Framework to access LinkedIn API. 
When reading posts from a group (using http://api.linkedin.com/v1/groups/[group_id]/posts:(some_arguments) together with start and count) sometimes I can load only several first posts from first page. When trying to load next page I receive empty result, but sometimes it works fine .
I can see the issue only when trying to read popular groups. It always works correctly when reading  my small group or my network. 
Maybe somebody has seen this issue before and knows what to do?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what "some arguments" are and the number of posts you're requesting, you may be running into a timeout.  If you're getting information about the profiles for the people who posted, commented and/or liked the posts as well as the post information itself, it can be an expensive call on the backend.

Try retrieving fewer posts at once, or reducing the number of additional fields you're requesting, and see if that resolves the problem.  If it does, please post in the forum at developer.linkedin.com and let us know about the issue, so we can make sure the engineers are aware of the timeouts.

Comment: Thank you for you answer.  I am using this url: [link](http://api.linkedin.com/v1/groups/87251/posts:(id,creator:(id,first-name,last-name,picture-url,headline),title,summary,likes,comments,creation-timestamp,attachment:(image-url,content-domain,content-url,title,summary),relation-to-viewer))   with pagination parameters start=0 and count=20, or  start = 20 and count = 20  etc. (each time 20 items are requested). The result may vary: 1. _count=>19,_start=>0,_total=>193;  or  2. _count=>20,_start=>0,_total=>199; or 3. just _total=>19 without _start and _count.

Comment: When loading second page I can even get: _start=>20,_total=>19; but I am sure the group has items more then 19. Thank you.

Comment: Yes, that looks like a bug.  I've let the backend folks know, but you'll just need to deal with some inconsistent behavior until someone can get to fixing it.  My apologies.